# How do Website like craigslist create content depending on the city your computer is located

Tags: http, backend, cname, web-development-server

I am looking to create a website that generates content depending on your city location. The best Example I found was Craigslit.They generate a web domain name like https://yourcity.craigslist.org/ when you either click on the city or it locates where you are. I was just wondering if I could get some help on how to build something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web pages are created using a template that doesn't change, populated with data that is selected from a database server, using your location to lookup appropriate items.

The subdomain (your city) is usually defined in the DNS record, just like www. There would be an entry for chicago.craigslist.org, for example.

**edit**

If you're asking how they know where you are, they can take a guess based on your IP address, however this isn't very reliable. Google does this also, when getting you search results that could be localized.

Comment: thank you I will look into DNS record . That is something  I am not familiar with

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, it is expected of you to type some stuff into google to (try) find your answer (like detect city from javascript will bring up a lot of results for your problem.)

But yeah you would use a service like https://ipstack.com/ to detect where you live, depending on where you live the accuracy increases. (EU has some rules and regulations that make it a lot less accurate than if you would be living in the US)

Once you have a database with content - For example craigslist has a database of second hand items sold by people from all over. When you connect to craigslist they ask a service where your request came from - then use some filter function based on your location to match the results.

Good luck

Comment: thanks yeah I already know how to detect the city . I just needed to understand how the data gets stored and displayed depending on the current city .I did not get how the sub domain was generated after you find the location of the person.

Comment: That would be part of the CMS they are useing, afraid I have no clue what CMS that is - there are plenty that offer sub domains.